# highlight/blink an item after pushing it on to a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of objects that I use to build an unordered list with ng-repeat.  After a new item is added I would like that item to blink or have some effect to draw the users attention to it.  This wouldn't be too difficult with jQuery but I'm trying to do it with only AngularJS

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="formData.itemText" />
      <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.itemText}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
app = angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"])

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.items = []
  $scope.formData = {}
  $scope.addItem = function(){
    $scope.items.push($scope.formData)
    $scope.formData = {}
  }
})
```

plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/kqOLpxy2HjPhxnjXHu2L?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/guide/animations) explains how you can achieve it in different ways.

Simple example:

```
.highlight {
  transition: all linear 300ms;
}
.highlight.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  color: firebrick;
}
.highlight.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" class="highlight">
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/vI0U8aopxoc4c4Bfx2Rh?p=preview

Comment: I think I overlooked the css part.  Simple!